# How to get x-axis start value in Flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I would like to know how to get x-axis start value in JS library Flot. I know x-axis value in the start (obviously, because I fill it with my own data), but if you set:

```
pan: {
     interactive: true
}
```

Than the user is able to pan through graph ([example here](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/navigate.html)) and if the user pans through graph, the x-values change. I looked inside jquery.flot.js to find where this values are computed but with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it. The solution was in front of me the whole time (example):

```
 var axes = plot.getAxes();
 var min = axes.xaxis.min;
```